# Is this related to a graph cut-edge (bridge)? Find the fast path in time from home to a shop/store

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

In http://codility.com/, exist a problem that say:

> There are N squares in your neighborhood and M direct roads connecting
>   them. The squares are numbered from 0 to N − 1. You are living in
>   square 0 and can reach it in 0 seconds. The stores are located in the
>   squares, one in each of them. You are given a map of the neighborhood
>   in the form of four zero-indexed arrays A, B, C and D. Each of the
>   arrays A, B, C contains M integers, while D contains N integers. 
>   For each I (0 ≤ I < M), the walking distance between squares A[I] and B[I]
>   is C[I] seconds (in either direction)
>
> There can be multiple roads connecting the same pair of squares, or a road with both ends entering
>   the same square.
>
> It is possible that some roads go through tunnels or
>   over bridges (that is, the graph of squares and roads doesn't have to
>   be planar).
>
> It is not guaranteed that you are able to reach all the
>   squares. For each J (0 ≤ J < N), the shop at square J will close in
>   D[J] seconds (if D[J] = −1, then the store is already closed); it is
>   possible to buy the food even if you reach the shop at the very last
>   second, when it closes.
>   Write a function:

```
int solution(int A[], int M, int B[], int M2, int C[], int M3, int D[], int N);
```

> that, given arrays A, B, C and D, returns the minimum
>   time (in seconds) needed to reach an open store. If it is impossible,
>   it should return −1.

My main problem is identify the problem. I don't have a heavy background in math. I do the test, it work as the sample data provide in the question, but after submit it, the website say is wrong for this data `data = [[6, 6, 3, 8, 8, 6, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 7], [3, 7, 5, 8, 0, 6, 3, 4, 1, 7, 1, 5, 3, 2], [8, 1, 9, 12, 11, 1, 8, 12, 3, 6, 12, 7, 4, 2], [-1, 1000000000, 1000000000, 999999999, 999999999, 999999999, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000]]`

I return -1, but it say I need to return 11. If I start at 0 (home) and try to locate the closer store I get stuck because 0 connect to 8 and 8 lead nowhere. I draw the graph and 0-8 is disconnected from the rest. I *suspect* is related to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory) and here is where my knowledge stop.

Is this the proper identification of the problem?

P.D: I'm more interested in understand the problem that have the python code.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but there is a store in square 8 and it's closing in 1000000000 seconds, meaning the 11 seconds to get from 0 to 8 is plenty.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth. But is this related to a graph bridge to fully solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll roughly explain a couple of approaches and hopefully you might get some ideas. Sounds like it would be good for your problem solving skills if you figure it out on your own.

Approach 1.

Use binary search to calculate the minimum time. For each guess in the binary search, have a function that works out if it is possible to reach a store in that time. (if it is possible, decrease the time, otherwise increase it). You can check if it's possible by depth first search of breadth first search (stopping on nodes that are further away than the guess).

Approach 2.

Use pythons heapq data structure. Start with the initial heap of [(0, start)] where 0 is distance 0 and start is the start node. Then for each node x connected to start, heappush (0 + dx, x) to the heapq (dx is the distance from start to x). Now pop the start. now pop the next best node. Check if the distance is less than D[x]. Continue.

Comment: I accept as means to solve the solution. However the proper answer to my questions is NO. I was overcomplicating this.